# Null output is overwritten with the next output

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The output of the code should not overwrite the null values.
I need the output in the attached format(1st output) and it is being shown in different format(2nd output). Please suggest me how to achieve this.

```
Customer_ID         Event_ID   Supp_CD
(null)              2534660914  (null)
(null)              2534660913  (null)
4000000000033919590 2534660916  (null)
7000000000491566892 2534660918  (null)
7000000000888215846 2534660917  (null)
7000000000945520325 2534660912  (null)
7000000000862996964 2534660919  (null)
7000000000554412111 2534660915  (null)
```

```
Customer_ID         Event_ID   Supp_CD
2534660914  
2534660913  
4000000000033919590 2534660916  
7000000000491566892 2534660918  
7000000000888215846 2534660917  
7000000000945520325 2534660912  
7000000000862996964 2534660919  
7000000000554412111 2534660915
```

I have written the SQL script, but the formatiing of DBMS_OUTPUT overwrites the null output. The last field SUPP_CD is a text and first two columns consists of numbers.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAPPED
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERMOUT ON

SPOOL /u01/apps/Miscellaneous/bin/spool.txt

DECLARE
  CSTID CDB_ADMIN.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG.cdb_customer_id%TYPE;
  EVNTID CDB_ADMIN.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG.cdb_pref_event_id%TYPE;
  SUPCD CDB_ADMIN.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG.supp_cd%TYPE;
  COUNTS INTEGER:=0;

  cursor c1 is
    <select * from A.B>;

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LPAD('Customer_ID',25)||LPAD('Event_ID',25)||RPAD('Supp_ID',25));

  OPEN C1;
  LOOP
    FETCH C1 INTO CSTID,EVNTID,SUPCD;
    EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(LPAD(CSTID,25)||LPAD(EVNTID,25)||RPAD(SUPCD,25));
    COUNTS := COUNTS+1;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NUMBER OF ROWS: ' || COUNTS);
END;
/

SPOOL OFF;
```

I tried by writing below piece of code by replacing this line with IF statement

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(LPAD(CSTID,25)||LPAD(EVNTID,25)||RPAD(SUPCD,25));
```

```
IF CSTID is null then
dbms_output.put_line(LPAD(coalesce(null,' '),25)||LPAD(EVNTID,25)||'  '||RPAD(SUPCD,40));
end if;
IF EVNTID is null then
dbms_output.put_line(LPAD(CSTID,25)||LPAD(coalesce(null,' '),25)||'  '||RPAD(SUPCD,40));
end if;
IF SUPCD is null then
dbms_output.put_line(LPAD(CSTID,25)||LPAD(EVNTID,25)||'  '||RPAD(coalesce(null,' '),40));
end if;
```

and the output is

```
              Customer_ID                 Event_ID  Supp_ID

                                        2534660914
               2534660914
                                        2534660913
               2534660913
      4000000000033919590               2534660916

      7000000000491566892               2534660918

      7000000000888215846               2534660917

      7000000000945520325               2534660912

      7000000000862996964               2534660919

      7000000000554412111               2534660915
```

Still figuring out the solution. Please let me know if this can be done in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace line:  `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(LPAD(CSTID,25)||LPAD(EVNTID,25)||RPAD(SUPCD,25));` as following , else other code will work fine

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    CASE
        WHEN CSTID IS NULL AND EVNTID IS NULL THEN LPAD(SUPCD, 25)
        WHEN CSTID IS NULL THEN
            CASE
                WHEN SUPCD IS NULL THEN LPAD(EVNTID, 25)
                ELSE LPAD(EVNTID, 25)
                     || RPAD(SUPCD, 25)
            END
        WHEN EVNTID IS NULL THEN
            CASE
                WHEN SUPCD IS NULL THEN LPAD(CSTID, 25)
                ELSE LPAD(CSTID, 25)
                     || RPAD(SUPCD, 25)
            END
        ELSE
            CASE
                WHEN SUPCD IS NULL THEN LPAD(CSTID, 25)
                                        || LPAD(EVNTID, 25)
                ELSE LPAD(CSTID, 25)
                     || LPAD(EVNTID, 25)
                     || RPAD(SUPCD, 25)
            END
    END
);
```

Hope, This will help.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('Customer_ID',20)||RPAD('Event_ID',20)||RPAD('Supp_ID',20));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    CASE
        WHEN CSTID IS NULL AND EVNTID IS NULL THEN RPAD(SUPCD, 20)
        WHEN CSTID IS NULL THEN
            CASE
                WHEN SUPCD IS NULL THEN RPAD(EVNTID, 20)
                ELSE RPAD(EVNTID, 20)
                     || RPAD(SUPCD, 20)
            END
        WHEN EVNTID IS NULL THEN
            CASE
                WHEN SUPCD IS NULL THEN RPAD(CSTID, 20)
                ELSE RPAD(CSTID, 20)
                     || RPAD(SUPCD, 20)
            END
        ELSE
            CASE
                WHEN SUPCD IS NULL THEN RPAD(CSTID, 20)
                                        || RPAD(EVNTID, 20)
                ELSE RPAD(CSTID, 20)
                     || RPAD(EVNTID, 20)
                     || RPAD(SUPCD, 20)
            END
    END
);
END;
/
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7f1f9cfeb307b8419ccaa2d86aa2743b) with few examples

Cheers!!

**----------**
**Update**
**----------**

You can use the following `DBMS_OUPUT`:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    CASE 
    WHEN CSTID IS NOT NULL THEN RPAD(CSTID, 20) 
    ELSE RPAD(' ', 20) 
    END
    ||
    CASE 
    WHEN EVNTID IS NOT NULL THEN RPAD(EVNTID, 20) 
    ELSE RPAD(' ', 20) 
    END
    ||
    CASE 
    WHEN SUPCD IS NOT NULL THEN RPAD(SUPCD, 20) 
    ELSE RPAD(' ', 20) 
    END
);
```

[DB<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cf71ae6e53408be4312921b7a096b527)

Cheers!!

Comment: I tried but it is still giving me the same output. Is there any way we can handle this by if-else?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: I checked your code in db<>Fiddle, in absence of CSTID and SUPCD values that is null, EVNTID value is shifted under Customer ID column.

Comment: Ohh my bad!! I misunderstood the requirement. I have made an update in my answer with new db<>fiddle demo. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `coalesce`

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(LPAD('Customer_ID',25,'.')||LPAD('Event_ID',25,'.'));
  dbms_output.put_line(LPAD(coalesce(null,' '),25,'.')||LPAD('2534660914',25,'.'));
end;
/
```

**dbms_output:**

```
..............Customer_ID.................Event_ID
........................ ...............2534660914
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d754a861574362dc61e5e584d87f1e26)*

Comment: I used coalesce, my modified script alongwith the output in above section. Please let me know if the results could be improved

Comment: you dont Need to use if, you can do it in one line `dbms_output.put_line(LPAD(coalesce(CSTID ,' '),25)||LPAD(coalesce(EVNTID,' '),25)||'  '||RPAD(coalesce(SUPCD,' ' ),40));`

Comment: @Christie i have add an example in *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=695becb0fcc4ec12cfe1417cd690f383)*

Comment: I tried it in db<>fiddle it  is working properly. But in my code it is throwing error as ```ORA-06502-character to number conversion error```